# Decrypt Bearer Token in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, signalr, bearer-token

Is there a way to read/decrypt a bearer token in the web api project?

My web api is also hosting SignalR hubs which are called from the browser via websocket.
Unlike my normal api calls I cannot add the authorization header here. Though I can send the token in the query string and read this in the SignalR hub.

By default the token is resolved by owin into a claims identity. What I need is to do this manually. How would I do that?

```
    OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions serverOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
    {
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(Config.TokenLifetime),
        Provider = new AuthProvider()
    };

    // Token Generation
    app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate); // wait for authenticate stage, so we get the windows principle for use with ntlm authentication
    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
    app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(serverOptions);
```

Comment: are you using OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions to generate tokens?

Comment: One way is to store the authentication provider in a static variable in the owin startup class and call it when you need to get the claims from a token.

Comment: @Nikola.Lukovic: yes

Comment: I have just added my configuration to the post

Comment: @MarcusH: Thanks, for the tipp. But how do I get the claims identity from the token using the provider?

Comment: @VinceBlack Check Nikolas answer:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that in `Startup.cs` you have a code similar to this:

```
var oAuthOpt = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
{
    Provider = new OAuthTokenProvider(
        req => req.Query.Get("bearer_token"),
        req => req.Query.Get("access_token"),
        req => req.Query.Get("refresh_token"),
        req => req.Query.Get("token"),
        req => req.Headers.Get("X-Token"))
};

app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthOpt);

app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    AllowInsecureHttp = true,
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString(settings.TokenEndpointBasePath),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = Util.AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan,
    Provider = new AuthorizationServerProvider(new AuthenticationService()),
});
```

What you have to do is to replace `oAuthOpt` with a public static field in `Startup.cs` and than use it when you need to unprotect your bearer tokens.

For SignalR i'm creating an Authorization attribute where i take that `oAuthOpt` and use it decode tokens.

This is how I do it:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class AuthorizeHubAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override bool AuthorizeHubConnection (HubDescriptor hubDescriptor, IRequest request)
    {
        var token = request.QueryString["Authorization"];
        var ticket = Startup.OAuthOpt.AccessTokenFormat.Unprotect(token);
        if ( ticket != null && ticket.Identity != null && ticket.Identity.IsAuthenticated )
        {
            request.Environment["server.User"] = new ClaimsPrincipal(ticket.Identity);
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    public override bool AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation (IHubIncomingInvokerContext hubIncomingInvokerContext, bool appliesToMethod)
    {
        var connectionId = hubIncomingInvokerContext.Hub.Context.ConnectionId;
        var environment = hubIncomingInvokerContext.Hub.Context.Request.Environment;
        var principal = environment["server.User"] as ClaimsPrincipal;
        if ( principal != null && principal.Identity != null && principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated )
        {
            hubIncomingInvokerContext.Hub.Context = new HubCallerContext(new Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin.ServerRequest(environment), connectionId);
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

> var ticket = Startup.OAuthOpt.AccessTokenFormat.Unprotect(token);

That line is the connection with `Startup.cs`

Comment: Thanks for your solution! Unfortunatelly it doesn't completely work for me: in AuthorizeHubConnection the ticket is null for some reason. However the token is correctly extracted from the request. How does your token string look like in the line above? Mine has the format 'Bearer <base64 token>'

Comment: can you try removing "Bearer " from the string and than passing it to Unprotect method

Comment: OK, I just cut off the Bearer part and now it works! Thanks a million!

Comment: I also struggled with this issue some time ago, here is a [complete GitHub project with authenticating WebApi and SignalR.](https://github.com/microsoft-dx/aspnet-fundamentals/tree/master/AspNetFundamentals/aspnet04%20-%20SimpleTokenAuthentication)
Best of luck!